# Login session strange behaviour with CakePHP

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, authentication

I developed web application based on CakePHP 1.3 platform. Application uses Auth component, so only authenticated users can use it.

But some of the users have problem that application log them out for some of the time. Problem is that I can not find out why they are getting logged out, since I don't face that problem. Also tried to be loged in application for few hours, and I do not have those problems at all.

Just to mention that sessions are defined to be saved as 'cake' and security level as low, in core.php file:

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake'); 
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

Also, they do not change ther IP address.

Can you give me some thoughts where can be a problem?

UPDATE: I need some of your thoughts... Can be a problem be caused by some of jQuery functions, that they kill some of the sessions or cookie values? Biggest issue here is that I can not simulate problems users have, because it works fine on my side... and only thing is to guess where problem is.........

Answer (score 2):

They get logged out if their session expires. Take a look here to increase the time on the session http://php-freelancer.in/2009/11/30/cakephp-session-timeout-or-change-session-length-in-cakephp/

Edit: If security isn't that much of an issue, consider using cookies to remember the login.

Comment: i did it in /app/config/core.php file: Configure::write('Session.timeout', '14400'); Configure::write('Security.level', 'low'); and it works for me, but for only some of them it does not works

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be possible that the server deletes the session after a certain time of inactivity. A possibility is having a cookie remember the user being logged in. A quick search lead me to this: http://lecterror.com/articles/view/cakephp-and-the-infamous-remember-me-cookie

Comment: it shoud not delete session after a certain time of inactivity, because session data is written as 'cake'. also, what confuses me is that only some of users face this problem. i'm not facing it, and i can not "simulate" it. also, i can not get more informations from those users about problem...

Comment: i found some advices that i shoud disable caching, by adding $this->disableCache(); in appController.php, in beforeFilter function. can that help me, and why?

Comment: and here is a link where i found that: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Auth-losting-authentication-with-no-reason-td1331403.html